# What are the differences between [will happen, will be happen, will be happened]?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

Could you explain what are the differences between useing (**will happen**, **will be happened**).

For example if I want to use those in this sentence,

1. Which one should I use?
2. What are the differences about thair meaning?

> What [.......] if I open this door?

Edit 2

> What **will happen** if I open this door?
>
> What **will be happend** if I open this door?

Could you explain the differences. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Will happen" is correct grammar.  It is the auxiliary verb "will" followed by the bare infinitive "happen".  It is used for events in the future.

"Will be happened" is the passive voice in the future.  This is not correct because "happen" is an intransitive verb. But if you use a transitive verb like "eat {something} you could say "The apple will be eaten."

"Will be happen" is incorrect grammar.  There is no English construction with "be+bare infinitive"